# Difference between SQL query and use of index on Datetime column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have simple table with index on `DateTime` column.

Can someone explain me which one of these two queries will use index?

```
CREATE TABLE exams
(
    name VARCHAR(50),
    grade INT,
    date DATETIME
);

CREATE INDEX date_idx ON exams(date);

SELECT * 
FROM exams 
WHERE date = '2018-01-01';      -- doesn't use index?

SELECT * 
FROM exams 
WHERE MONTH(date) = 1;      -- uses index?
```

Comment: I don't believe that the second query uses the index, please **[edit]** your question and add the execution plan. And tell us which database product you are using

Comment: I have used ctrl +L to see execution plan and I can see that the first one does not use index and the second one does. It is MSSQL.

Comment: Can u try to apply casting as date in first query and check?

Comment: As @a_horse_with_no_name mentioned neither one of these queries use the index.

Comment: For the first query "Missing Index - CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX".

Comment: You use `SELECT *` query so to avoid expensive key lookups the optimizer prefers table scan (I guess you have many rows that meet the condition `date= '2018-01-01'` and the optimizer is able to get the information from the index statistics). For the second query that statistics can't be used and the optimizer decides to scan your index for some reason.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are different ways this to be solved by the SQL Engine. Let's insert some sample data in your table:

```
DROP TABLE if exists exams;

CREATE TABLE exams(
  name varchar(50),
  grade INT,
  date datetime
);

INSERT exams
SELECT TOP (5000)  CONCAT('name', row_number() over(order by t1.number))
                   ,6
                   ,'2019-07-01'
FROM master..spt_values t1 
CROSS JOIN master..spt_values t2

INSERT exams
SELECT TOP (5)  CONCAT('name', row_number() over(order by t1.number))
                   ,6
                   ,'2019-07-02'
FROM master..spt_values t1 
CROSS JOIN master..spt_values t2

CREATE INDEX date_idx ON exams(date);
```

As you can see, we have inserted:

- 5 000 rows for date `2019-07-01`
- 5 rows for date `2019-07-02`

Let's execute the following queries, now:

```
SELECT * FROM exams WHERE date= '2019-07-01'; 

SELECT * FROM exams WHERE date= '2019-07-02'; 

SELECT * FROM exams WHERE MONTH(date)=1;
```

and check the execution plans:

[image]

In the first query, the engine knows (because of the statistics) that almost all of the data is going to be read, so it performs `table scan` on your heap.

In the second query, the engine see that only few of the records are going to be return, so there is no need to read all the data - it uses the index, and performs `index seek`.

In the last case, the index can't be used, because the query si not [sargable](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2010/06/sargable-why-string-is-slow/).

So, the engine decides if or not to use an index, and if or not to perform seek or scan. The only thing you can do is to make sure your indexes are covering, your statistics are updated and your queries are sargable.

Answer (score 4):

Well, I believe that the truth is quite inversed:

First query uses index, while second DOES NOT.

Why second query doesn't use index? Because indexed column is wrapped in a function which prevents SQL Server from using index.

Index can be thought of as way of storing records. Applying function to indexed column may alter order of stored records, thus index can be no longer valid when using function.

Comment: Thanks, they both show "Table scan", but for the first query I am getting "Missing Index - CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX". I don't know how to tell if which one uses index.

Comment: In SQL Server 2008 both will use the index, while if you test it on db<>fiddle none of them will use the index instead it's full table scan.

Comment: @Sami It also depends if SQL Server will "think" that using index is useful. I guess on small tables index won't be used.

Comment: @MichałTurczyn I have added 30000+ rows.